# Request Headers: Accept: / Authorization: Basic XCODE

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-headers, afnetworking

I have to do an app with login.The user can reset the pass . When he do that an email with a temporary password is sent to user. My problem is : how to include this : The authorization header format: 
Authorization: Basic toBase64(username:passwordhash)

Request  Headers:

```
Accept: */* 
Authorization: Basic bWFybGU6JDJ5JDA3JG0wNGtMMjJ6TlZBTVV0RGEwLkVjUk9HaFRhb
```

VJDNjRhZFk0MzFKQWppT3FJQlV4TDQ0MDVD .

i have a method for updatePasword:

```
+ (void)updatePassword:(NSString *)password succes:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure {
    NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/user/%@", BASE_URL,         [SessionHelper currentSession].currentUserID];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:[SessionHelper currentSession].currentUser.username password:[SessionHelper currentSession].currentPasswordHash];

    [manager PUT:urlString parameters:@{@"password":password} success:success failure:failure];
}
```

When i want to change password this is happen :

```
2014-08-16 16:24:19.778 ******[1052:60b] sending request: PUT http://*******.my.phpcloud.com/WS/user/61
2014-08-16 16:24:19.779 *******[1052:60b] request body: {"password":"passWORD1"}
2014-08-16 16:24:20.675 *****[1052:6517] request: PUT http://********.my.phpcloud.com/WS/user/61
2014-08-16 16:24:20.676 *******[1052:6517] received error: Request failed: unauthorized (401), got 34845072
```

What to do for making this authorized?

Comment: Only the server-side knows the password and is the only thing that can pass it to the app, You need to implement another form of sever-client validation such as appcode or secret key...